# Optimx not recognizing "Nelder-Mead" method of optimization

Tags: programming, portfolio-optimization

I'm trying to run an optimization using optimx, specifically using the Nelder-Mead method since it is a not-derivative method.  Below is my code:

```
    test<-optimx(c(0.45, 1.4),fn=testfunc,gr=NULL, hess=NULL, lower=c(0,0), upper=c(1.0, 1.5), method="Nelder-Mead", itnmax = 1, hessian=FALSE,
                  control=list(save.failures=TRUE, kkt=FALSE, trace=1))
```

However, it appears that R isn't recognizing "Nelder-Mead as a viable method.  Am I mistaken that "Nelder-Mead" is a method that one can specify in optimx?  Or perhaps I'm entering the ID for Nelder-Mead incorrectly?  Below is the warning message when I try to run the above code:

```
    Warning messages:
    1: In optimx.setup(par, fn, gr, hess, lower, upper, method, itnmax,  :
      optimx: No match to available methods
    2: In optimx.setup(par, fn, gr, hess, lower, upper, method, itnmax,  :
      Default method when bounds specified is L-BFGS-B to match optim()
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the `optim()` function instead?

Comment: No there is not.  Do you think that is prefered to optimx?

Comment: Before trying the `optim()` function, try to remove your lower and upper bounds from the optimx and see if it runs with the Nelder-Mead method. It is specified [in the documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/optimx/optimx.pdf), that the bounds are only used for the L-BFGS-B method (*see p. 36*).

Comment: Yep, that did it.  Without the bounds it functions correctly.  Not exactly how I want it to, but it does work.  I would like to be able to incorporate upper and lower bounds into the optimization and still use a non-derivative based method.  Is that possible?

Comment: Hi: If you want derivative free methods, don't use optim because everything except nelder mead is derivative based. Instead,  check out the dfoptim package by Ravi Varhadan. I've never used it but Ravi is another optimization expert ( besides John Nash )  in the R community so it can be trusted.